# Sql Query to find Counts

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table as below .

```
Id Product1 Product2 Product3
1     1      null     null
2     1       2       null
3     3       1       null
4     2       3        1
```

Now I would like to write a query to count the entries with Product 1.
In the above case it is 2 for Product1 , 1 for Product2 and 1 for Product 3

I came up with a query something like this.

```
select
Count(Product1) +
Count(Product2) +
Count(Product3)
from  
Table 
where Product1  =  1
```

But it gives me an inaccurate result.
Is there a way I can get the number of occurances for each product ?

**Group By**

Desired output would be something like this :

```
ProductID Product1Count Product2Count Product3Count 
  1           2              1             1                    
  2           1              1             0
  3           1              1             0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select Count(CASE WHEN Product1 = 1 THEN 1 END) +
       Count(CASE WHEN Product2 = 1 THEN 1 END) +
       Count(CASE WHEN Product3 = 1 THEN 1 END)
from   Table1 
where  1 IN (Product1, Product2, Product3)
```

- [SQLFIddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e9e43/1)

The reason for adding this line: `where  1 IN (Product1, Product2, Product3)` is to count only on the affected rows, thus making it more faster than running through all records.

Comment: Hey Thank you the solution works ! Could you tell me what I can do if I want to group the counts by products ? like getting a count for product1 , product2 and product3

Comment: can you show your desired output? or maybe this time you need to add `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Desired output would be something like this :

Comment: I can't get the logic, maybe you could add more explaination and open new question on it `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work:

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN Product1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+ SUM(CASE WHEN Product2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+ SUM(CASE WHEN Product3 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM Table
```